# How to minus two things together in JavaScript...?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game and i need to deduct the right amount of points. This statement I have doesn't work (the playerPower) part.

```
function checkCol(cell, row){
    var color = map[row][cell];
    console.log(color);
    if (color == "g") {
        alert("Green");
        playerPower -= onGrass - passengerBayPower
    } else if (color == "b") {
        alert("Brown");
        playerPower -= onRock - passengerBayPower
    } else if (color == "w") {
        alert("White");
        playerPower -= onIce - passengerBayPower
    }
```

Is there something wrong with the -= and then -?

Comment: I don't know the associativity off the top of my head, but adding some parentheses might help.

Comment: Like Joe said, It should be working if you surroung the substract with parentheses.

Comment: won't - - something become + ? :)

Comment: Or use `+` on the right side..

Comment: `x = 25;` `x -= 10 - 5 ;` works fine in my browser console.  Correct answer is `25 - 5 = 20`.

Answer (score 1):

you could simplify it by:

```
var color = map[row][cell];
var diff = 0;
    console.log(color);
    if (color == "g") {
        alert("Green");
        diff = onGrass - passengerBayPower
    } else if (color == "b") {
        alert("Brown");
        diff = onRock - passengerBayPower
    } else if (color == "w") {
        alert("White");
        diff = onIce - passengerBayPower
    }
    playerPower -= diff;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's give some values to your variables. Let's say `playerPower` is 10, `onGrass` is 2 and `passengerBayPower` is 4. You might expect the answer to be `10 - 2 - 4 = 4`, right? Wrong...

```
playerPower -= onGrass - passengerBayPower
```

corresponds to...

```
playerPower = playerPower - (onGrass - passengerBayPower)
            = playerPower - onGrass + passengerBayPower
                                // ^^^ using basic mathematics
```

Which means you get `10 - 2` ***`+`*** `4 = 12`

To fix, use `onGrass + passengerBayPower`, or remove the `passengerBayPower` altogether and throw this on the end:

```
playerPower -= passengerBayPower;
```

Since that's common to all cases.

Comment: I assumed he knew basic math.  Guess I assumed wrong?

Comment: @Paul When you're taught that `x -= y` is short for `x = x - y`, it's not a far stretch to assume that `x -= y - z` is short for `x = x - y - z` (no parentheses) but... yeah XD